# Listen to login check or login form post

Tags: symfony, authentication

The context:
I want to redirect any request to a /blocked URL when someone has attempted to log to the same username from the same IP more than N times.

I want to redirect and  skip checking credentials, so I'd need to set a method as onAuthenticationCheck for checking if the login attempts limit has been overpassed (counting the attempts DB stored), so it would cancel the login process before checking the password but I'd be able of sending a specific flash message.

I have tried with kernelListeners, but it's only working on GET requests.

```
 public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {

        $this->preventForceLogin($event);
    }


private function preventForceLogin($event) {

    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if ($request->getMethod() === 'GET') {
        return;
    }
     // THE CODE BELOW IS NOW USELESS AS THE LOGIN POST
    // IS UNEXPECTEDLY NOT REACHING THIS METHOD !!

    $route = $this->getRoute($request);

    if ($route === 'login' || $route === 'forgot') {
        $username = $request->request->get('_username');
        if ($this->getAttempts($username) > 4) {
            $url = $this->router->generate('wait');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

So if I would managed to intercept the login POST, I'll still need to know how to prevent propagation in order to avoid the login check prior to set the Response.

I think that maybe the best option would be create an specific Form Subscriber. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was not being able to catch the POST event, was simple. My listener got no priority (yml tag priority on services.yml) so the Symfony out-of-the-box listeners, did their work before so no POST were available to my listener. In this case, my problem was the `Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\FirewallListener::onKernelRequest()` listed on the profiler Events with priority 8, so the solution for my case is adding the tag priority:9 to my Kernel Listener.